# To capitalize or not quoted text after be form

Tags: capitalization, quotations

Which one is correct:

According to Speechpad, transcription is "**A** text document that contains a transcript of everything that is spoken in an audio or video file."

or

According to Speechpad, transcription is "**a** text document that contains a transcript of everything that is spoken in an audio or video file."

Comment: If it's a "direct quote" it should be capitalized.

Comment: Very closely related, and possibly dupes: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/59052 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/50605

Answer (score 1):

As @MorganFR mentions in the comments, direct quotes should not be changed (at all), unless you indicate the change.

If you want to use a direct quote, but use proper grammar and/or punctuation, you can use [square brackets](http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/brackets.html#changeincapitalization):

> According to Speechpad, transcription is "[a] text document that contains a transcript of everything that is spoken in an audio or video file."